# What is the relationship between between the quotient groups $G/\overline{H}$ and $N(H)/H$?

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

Given a group $G$ and a subgroup $H\subseteq G$, let $\overline{H}=\langle ghg^{-1}\mid h\in H\text{ and } g\in G\rangle$ be the normal closure of $H$ and $N(H)=\{g\in G\mid gHg^{-1}=H\}$ be the normalizer of $H$. What is the relationship between quotient groups $G/\overline{H}$ and $N(H)/H$?

It is trivial for an abelian group such that $G/\overline{H}=N(H)/H$ as $\overline{H}=H$ and $N(H)=G$. Does this equality can also be extended to non-abelian group? Or there is a simple counter example for this (better to be a finite group)? If they are not equal, do they have any other relationships?

Comment: There are lots of cases where they are not isomorphic. Take $G=A_5$, $H=\langle (12)(34)\rangle$. The normal closure is $A_5$, so the quotient $G/\overline{H}$ is trivial. But $(13)(24)$ and $(14)(23)$ centralize, hence normalize $H$, so $N(H)/H$ is not trivial.

Comment: Actual equality holds if and only if $H$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: I am a bit doubt about "equality holds if and only if 
 is normal in ". I tried some examples of $S_3$ and $D_6$. There are some non-trivial examples holds true.

Comment: Equality requires that the subgroup you are moding out by be the same. You probably found examples where the quotients are *isomorphic*.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the difference between equality and isomorphic